# SEO and user-friendly URLs for multi-language website

Tags: url, seo, multilingual, usability

Let's say I have a website that has 2 languages, one uses Latin and the second one Cyrillic transcriptions in URLs.

For example:

- example.com/link
- example.com/ссылка

My question is which is more user and SEO friendly, if I leave them as is or if I add the language prefix, so they'd become

- example.com/en/link
- example.com/ru/ссылка

I understand that such subdirectories should be used if I have languages that are similar and then the user wouldn't be confused, but does that also apply in my case?

Comment: What are the homepage URLs of these two sites?

Comment: These pages are located on one website (erahoius.ee) and thanks to the answer below programmers have already inserted these virtual language subdirectories into the URLs.

Comment: These type of questions belong to: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use the second one for better SEO results.

```
example.com/en/link
example.com/ru/ссылка
```

Google likes the tree-like structure. Of course you can use the main language without prefix.

Also it's better to have all languages in one domain:

```
domain.com/en
domain.com/ru
```

not on subdomains like this

```
en.domain.com
ru.domain.com
```

Wish you luck.

Comment: Thank you. I hope Google agrees with you.

Comment: Some time ago I had research this "problem". If you use the first approach, Google can be confused, what is your website primary language and what language audience you have. 
So I believe the best thing to do is to make domain.com with your most important language. And use prefixes for the other languages. 
If you make a subdomains - en.domain.com, ru.domain.com & etc... you will spread the domain power to subdomains, because Google sees every subdomain like a different website.